# Android - Failure while parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, http, url

I have a JSON table on a URL which I'm trying to parse. It starts with node { so I'm parsing as JSONObject. But I'm getting the error below :

```
11-21 02:33:38.660: E/JSON Parser(20307): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after n at character 7 of {n    "videos": [n        {n            "title": "Big Buck Bunny",n            "thumbnail": "http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/poster.jpg",n            "video_url": "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"n        },n        {n            "title": "Perfect Lamborghini Impression",n            "thumbnail": "http://www.mp4point.com/images/thumb/perfect-lamborghini-impression.jpg",n            "video_url": "http://www.mp4point.com/downloads/7b0de690da55.mp4"n        },n        {n            "title": "Flute Beatboxing",n            "thumbnail": "http://www.mp4point.com/images/thumb/flute-beatboxing.jpg",n            "video_url": "http://www.mp4point.com/downloads/bd8bda782093.mp4"n        }n    ]n}n
```

I'm using the code below for Parsing :

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser(){

    }
    public JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
              }
              is.close();
              json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
              jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
          }
}
```

Any ideas what might be causing problems here? It's really frustrating and I am trying to find the mistake here for like 3 hours now. This is the only stepback for me to move forward with the App. Appreciate any help.

Edit :

```
{
    "videos": [
        {
            "title": "Big Buck Bunny",
            "thumbnail": "http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/poster.jpg",
            "video_url": "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
        },
        {
            "title": "Perfect Lamborghini Impression",
            "thumbnail": "http://www.mp4point.com/images/thumb/perfect-lamborghini-impression.jpg",
            "video_url": "http://www.mp4point.com/downloads/7b0de690da55.mp4"
        },
        {
            "title": "Flute Beatboxing",
            "thumbnail": "http://www.mp4point.com/images/thumb/flute-beatboxing.jpg",
            "video_url": "http://www.mp4point.com/downloads/bd8bda782093.mp4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post the JSON its trying to parse?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is well-formed? It would be helpful to see a sample.

Comment: It is appended on the post.

Comment: What does this line do: `sb.append(line + "n");`? It seems to be adding an `n` into your JSON data. That won't help you parse it.

Comment: If I read, I'm going to the next line with that and pass the n on the point. I've tried to play with it but than it does not even read the data anymore. Problem must be something else.

Comment: Taking that back, you are definetly right Mike. Getting rid of the "n" and leaving the line alone solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code which reads the response is inserting extraneous 'n' characters at the end of each line:

```
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
          }
```

Try changing it to

```
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the JSON is wrong. I've checked the syntax of it like 10 times.